# Реализация слушателя для массива кнопок

Tags: java, swing

пишу приложение на JFrame. Есть 4 класса. Подскажите как реализовать слушатель для массива кнопок. Будет еще приятнее, если проверите весь код на адекватность(кому интересно)

1 класс с фреймом и панелью

```
public class Main extends JFrame{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Main().setWindow();
    }

    private void setWindow(){
        setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        setContentPane(new Controller().setPanel());
        setUndecorated(true);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

2 класс для подмены панелей в будущем

```
public class Controller {
private static boolean Flag = true;
private Creater creater = new Creater();

private ArrayList<JButton> btnList = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<JLabel> lblList = new ArrayList<>();

JPanel setPanel(){
    if(Flag){ menu(); }
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(null);
    for(JButton pair : btnList){ panel.add(pair); }
    for(JLabel pair : lblList){ panel.add(pair); }
    return panel;
}

private void menu(){
    btnList.add(creater.setButton(new JButton(), "Игра", 545, 200, 300, 50));
    btnList.add(creater.setButton(new JButton(), "Настройки", 545, 300, 300, 50));
    btnList.add(creater.setButton(new JButton(), "X", 1316, 0, 50, 30));
    lblList.add(creater.setLabel(new JLabel(), "Test", 680, 10, 100, 100));

    for (JButton pair : btnList){
        pair.addActionListener(new Listener()); // <<< ПРОБЛЕМА ЗДЕСЬ
    }
}
public void Game(){
    creater.setButton(new JButton(), "Тест", 300, 100, 300, 50);
}}
```

3 класс для создания кнопок

```
class Creater {

JButton setButton(JButton btn, String btnName, int posX, int posY, int sizeW, int sizeH) {
    JButton button = new JButton(btnName);
    button.setLocation(posX, posY);
    button.setSize(sizeW, sizeH);
    return button;
}

JLabel setLabel(JLabel lbl, String labelName, int posX, int posY, int sizeW, int sizeH){
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Test");
    label.setLocation(posX, posY);
    label.setSize(sizeW, sizeH);
    return label;
}}
```

4 класс - сам слушатель. Но нужен ли вообще этот класс?

```
public class Listener implements ActionListener {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

}}
```

Принимаю любую критику и замечания с вашей стороны

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Собственный класс - слушатель не нужен, все давно написано:

```
for (JButton pair : btnList) {
    pair.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
        //your code
    });
}
```

На быструю руку получилось примерно так:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public final class Main extends JFrame {

    private final boolean FLAG;

    public Main() {
        FLAG = true;
        addComponents(new JPanel(null));        
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(1024, 800);        
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        //setUndecorated(true);
        setVisible(true);
    }


    private JPanel addComponents(JPanel mainPanel) {
        if (FLAG) {
            createButton(mainPanel, "Игра", 200, 200, 300, 50);
            createButton(mainPanel, "Настройки", 200, 300, 300, 50);
            createButton(mainPanel, "X", 500, 0, 50, 30);
            createLabel(mainPanel, "Test", 500, 10, 100, 100);
        }
        return mainPanel;
    }

    private JButton createButton(JComponent mainComponent, String name, int posX, int posY, int sizeW, int sizeH) {
        JButton button = new JButton(name);        
        button.addActionListener((java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) -> {
            //your code
        });
        return createComponent(mainComponent, button, posX, posY, sizeW, sizeH);
    }
    private JLabel createLabel(JComponent mainComponent, String name, int posX, int posY, int sizeW, int sizeH) {
        return createComponent(mainComponent, new JLabel(name), posX, posY, sizeW, sizeH);
    }    
    private <T extends JComponent> T createComponent(JComponent mainComponent, T component, 
            int posX, int posY, int sizeW, int sizeH) {
        component.setLocation(posX, posY);
        component.setSize(sizeW, sizeH);
        mainComponent.add(component);
        return component;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

}
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно!

Comment: Не за что, но код откровенно плохой)) Классы и методы созданы наугад. Много лишнего кода. Все можно упростить. Чуть позже отредактирую ответ, попробую сделать небольшой рефакторинг.

Comment: Да я тоже через день посмотрел на свое творение и задался вопросом: зачем мне вообще флаг) И еще пару правок сделал. Но ваш вариант я с нетерпением буду ждать

Comment: я его уже выложил, ждать не надо (ответ откорретирован)